# Change Dataframe Column Name by mapping with other Dataframe Column, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to change columns name of Dataframe "Data" if column matching with XML_Data['conceptRef'], columns name contains in XML_Data['Dimension_Name_EN']

Data.columns

```
Index(['MEASURE', 'INDEX', 'STAGE', 'SOURCE', 'DESTINATION', 'FREQUENCY', 'VALUE', 'DATE'], dtype='object')
```

XML_Data:

```
   Order                codelist   conceptRef    Dimension_Name_EN
0      1      CL_PPI_SOP_MEASURE      MEASURE              Measure
1      2        CL_PPI_SOP_INDEX        INDEX                Index
2      3        CL_PPI_SOP_STAGE        STAGE  Stage of Production
3      4       CL_PPI_SOP_SOURCE       SOURCE               Source
4      5  CL_PPI_SOP_DESTINATION  DESTINATION          Destination
```

If column ('FREQUENCY', 'VALUE', 'DATE') not present in other dataframe then keep as it is.

Comment: so, just to be clear 

you have 2 data frames,

one with n columns

and one with fixed columns

if columns in the first dataframe are found in the 2nd then you want to change their values? additionally, you first want to check if the columns does contain Frequency,value or date then you want to leave it as it is? 

Further to that, what have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` by dictionary created by zip columns of `XML_Data` DataFrame:

```
d = dict(zip(XML_Data['conceptRef'], XML_Data['Dimension_Name_EN']))
Data = Data.rename(columns=d)
```